# Error cloning virtual machine: A specified parameter was not correct: spec.pool

Tags: virtual-machine, vsphere

I want to create a VM on VSphere with OpenTofu but was met with some problems.
After creating an ubuntu image, I received an error when attempting to create VM using the image with said message:

> " Error: error cloning virtual machine: A specified parameter was not correct: spec.pool".

Using ChatGPT, I got a response that said there could be an error with resource pool id or datastore id but I want to make sure that it really was an id error and not other kind of issues. How can I confirm that ?

[image]

This is my main.tf code:
[image]

[image]